# Can you print/write the result of screen.debug() to a file?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library

In one of my tests I am expecting some kind of DOM change. However, the page it's on is quite long.

So what I usually do for smaller components is to use `screen.debug()` method. But since the file is quite long, I started to also run the test task with `DEBUG_PRINT_LIMIT=50000`. Now that eventually got the result I got.

But that made me wonder, is it perhaps possible to save the output in a file?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the docs, [screen.debug](https://testing-library.com/docs/dom-testing-library/api-queries#screendebug) is essentially a shortcut for `console.log(prettyDOM())`.

So you could just use `prettyDOM()` directly, and do whatever with the result.

I would do `copy(prettyDOM())` to put it on the clipboard and then paste it in a text file manually (in Chrome) or save it into a file (in node).

Here is a helper function demonstrating how to use it to create a file with the content of the DOM:

```js
import fs from "node:fs";
import { prettyDOM } from "@testing-library/dom";

export function dump(element) {
  fs.mkdirSync("dump", { recursive: true });
  fs.writeFileSync(
    `dump/${Date.now()}.html`,
    prettyDOM(element, 1000000, { highlight: false }) || "");
};
```

Comment: interesting. Any idea for the "copy"? Something like "document.execCommand("copy")" is probably not possible in a JEST file.

Comment: Can't you just import `fs` in the test and write the results of `prettyDOM()` to a file?

Comment: @zord i tried that, I get a bunch of gibberish `[39m [36m` etc

Comment: @johnk you can configure prettyDOM.
`fs.writeFileSync("dump.html",
    prettyDOM(undefined, undefined, { highlight: false }) || "")`