# VItest - how to increase number of log lines

Tags: reactjs, frontend, vite, vitest

When using vitest to test a UI, I'm trying to do a `screen.getBy..` that fails.
When it fails, I see the rendered HTML as a log, but it cuts off abruptly so that I can't see the elements that actually interest me.
I've tried adding the env var DEBUG_PRINT_LIMIT=1000000 - didnt work.
Tried doing a screen.debug(..)  - also didn't work .
Any idea how I can view the full log ?
Also on that same note, is there any way that I can view the current state of the page I'm rendering in a browser.. ?

Thanks !

Comment: Maybe this answer here can help you to see full log: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62703526/can-you-print-write-the-result-of-screen-debug-to-a-file